# Can I cast/convert templates to other template types?

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing some code where I will need to often switch between homogenous and cartesian coordinates:

```
(x, y, z) -> (x, y, z, w = 1)
(x, y, z, w) -> (x/w, y/w, z/w)
```

I am using a library that already has templates for a vector of arbitrary size and type, as well as typedefs for a few common ones like so:

```
typedef vec<3,  float> Vec3f;
typedef vec<4,  float> Vec4f;
```

I'm curious if there is a way I can add to this, so I can easily switch between the two using the homogenous <-> cartesian relationship shown above.  I'd like to have something like this:

```
Vec3f cart1(10, 15, 20);
Vec4f homo1;
homo1 = (Vec4f) cart1;
std::cout << "homo1: " << homo1 << std::endl;

Vec4f homo2(10, 15, 20, 5);
Vec3f cart2;
cart2 = (Vec3f) homo2;
std::cout << "cart2: " << cart2 << std::endl;
```

Which would output the following(the vector templates have overloaded << operators for printing):

```
homo1: 10, 15, 20, 1
cart2: 2, 3, 4
```

Here is the relevant template code from the header, note that I added the vec<4, T> part:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

template<size_t DimCols,size_t DimRows,typename T> class mat;

template <size_t DIM, typename T> struct vec {
    vec() { for (size_t i=DIM; i--; data_[i] = T()); }
          T& operator[](const size_t i)       { assert(i<DIM); return data_[i]; }
    const T& operator[](const size_t i) const { assert(i<DIM); return data_[i]; }
private:
    T data_[DIM];
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template <typename T> struct vec<3,T> {
    vec() : x(T()), y(T()), z(T()) {}
    vec(T X, T Y, T Z) : x(X), y(Y), z(Z) {}
    template <class U> vec<3,T>(const vec<3,U> &v);
          T& operator[](const size_t i)       { assert(i<3); return i<=0 ? x : (1==i ? y : z); }
    const T& operator[](const size_t i) const { assert(i<3); return i<=0 ? x : (1==i ? y : z); }
    float norm() { return std::sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z); }
    vec<3,T> & normalize(T l=1) { *this = (*this)*(l/norm()); return *this; }

    T x,y,z;
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// my Vec4f template
template <typename T> struct vec<4,T> {
    vec() : x(T()), y(T()), z(T()), w(T()) {}
    vec(T X, T Y, T Z) : x(X), y(Y), z(Z), w(1.f) {}
    template <class U> vec<4,T>(const vec<4,U> &v);
          T& operator[](const size_t i)       { assert(i<4); return i<=0 ? x : (1==i ? y : (2==i ? z : w)); }
    const T& operator[](const size_t i) const { assert(i<4); return i<=0 ? x : (1==i ? y : (2==i ? z : w)); }

    T x,y,z,w;
};

typedef vec<3,  float> Vec3f;
typedef vec<4,  float> Vec4f;
```

Now, the matching .cpp file has code that already looks to do this, just not for the types that I want:

```
template <> template <> vec<3,int>  ::vec(const vec<3,float> &v) : x(int(v.x+.5f)),y(int(v.y+.5f)),z(int(v.z+.5f)) {};
template <> template <> vec<3,float>::vec(const vec<3,int> &v)   : x(v.x),y(v.y),z(v.z) {};
```

I don't quite understand this layout(the template <> template <> part), but it's apparent that this allows casting between vectors of ints/floats, and I've confirmed this.  However, when I tried to do the same, I'm getting errors:

```
template <> template <> vec<3,float>::vec(const vec<4,float> &v) : x(v.x / v.w),y(v.y / v.w),z(v.z / v.w) {};
template <> template <> vec<4,float>::vec(const vec<3,float> &v) : x(v.x),y(v.y),z(v.z),w(1.f) {};
```

Compiling with the above gives this:

```
tinyrenderer-files/geometry.cpp:9:25: error: template-id ‘vec<>’ for ‘vec<3, float>::vec(const vec<4, float>&)’ does not match any template declaration
 template <> template <> vec<3,float>::vec(const vec<4,float> &v) : x(v.x / v.w),y(v.y / v.w),z(v.z / v.w) {};
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from tinyrenderer-files/geometry.cpp:1:0:
tinyrenderer-files/geometry.h:32:30: note: candidates are: constexpr vec<3, float>::vec(vec<3, float>&&)
 template <typename T> struct vec<3,T> {
                              ^~~~~~~~
tinyrenderer-files/geometry.h:32:30: note:                 constexpr vec<3, float>::vec(const vec<3, float>&)
tinyrenderer-files/geometry.h:35:24: note:                 template<class U> vec<3, T>::vec(const vec<3, U>&) [with U = U; T = float]
     template <class U> vec<3,T>(const vec<3,U> &v);
                        ^~~~~~~~
tinyrenderer-files/geometry.h:34:5: note:                 vec<3, T>::vec(T, T, T) [with T = float]
     vec(T X, T Y, T Z) : x(X), y(Y), z(Z) {}
     ^~~
tinyrenderer-files/geometry.h:33:5: note:                 vec<3, T>::vec() [with T = float]
     vec() : x(T()), y(T()), z(T()) {}
     ^~~
tinyrenderer-files/geometry.cpp:10:25: error: template-id ‘vec<>’ for ‘vec<4, float>::vec(const vec<3, float>&)’ does not match any template declaration
 template <> template <> vec<4,float>::vec(const vec<3,float> &v) : x(v.x),y(v.y),z(v.z),w(1.f) {};
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from tinyrenderer-files/geometry.cpp:1:0:
tinyrenderer-files/geometry.h:47:30: note: candidates are: constexpr vec<4, float>::vec(vec<4, float>&&)
 template <typename T> struct vec<4,T> {
                              ^~~~~~~~
tinyrenderer-files/geometry.h:47:30: note:                 constexpr vec<4, float>::vec(const vec<4, float>&)
tinyrenderer-files/geometry.h:50:24: note:                 template<class U> vec<4, T>::vec(const vec<4, U>&) [with U = U; T = float]
     template <class U> vec<4,T>(const vec<4,U> &v);
                        ^~~~~~~~
tinyrenderer-files/geometry.h:49:5: note:                 vec<4, T>::vec(T, T, T) [with T = float]
     vec(T X, T Y, T Z) : x(X), y(Y), z(Z), w(1.f) {}
     ^~~
tinyrenderer-files/geometry.h:48:5: note:                 vec<4, T>::vec() [with T = float]
     vec() : x(T()), y(T()), z(T()), w(T()) {}
     ^~~
```

The "does not match any template declaration" seems to be an obvious clue but I'm not sure why the other lines that were already there are working, as they don't seem to declare anything extra?

I'm hoping someone can help:

- Explain the code(template <> template <>) that seems to let me cast between float/int vectors(that was already present in the library)
- Explain why the code I added isn't working when on the surface it seems to be very similar

Let me know if I need to provide any other snippets of code, perhaps there's something there that doesn't look relevant but is.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass.

```
class Homogeneous;
class Cartesian : public Vec3f
{
    Cartesian () : Vec3f() {}
    Cartesian (float a, float b, float c) : Vec3f(a, b, c, d) {}
    explicit Cartesian (const Homogeneous& v); // Define later, we don't know Homogeneous yet
}

class Homogeneous : public Vec4f
{
public:
    Homogeneous() : Vec4f() {}
    Homogeneous(float a, float b, float c, float d) : Vec4f(a, b, c, d) {}
    explicit Homogeneous(const Cartesian& v) : Vec4f() { // do conversion }
}

Cartesian::Cartesian (const Homogeneous& v) : Vec3f() { // do conversion }
```

Something like that. It has also the added benefit that is more typesafe than using Vec3f.

If you use public inheretancy without virtual destructor, you should do something like

```
static_assert(sizeof(Cartesian) == sizeof(Vec3f), "Don't");
static_assert(sizeof(Homogeneous) == sizeof(Vec4f), "Don't");
```

Regards.

Comment: Can you explain the last part?  Where would I put those static_asserts?

Comment: When you do public inheritance you should either a) use polymorphism (have a virtual destructor) or b) ensure that the size remains the same (you can't add any size occupying member to the class); you can ensure that by putting the `static_assert` anywhere in your code (but the best place would be just below the class definition). So you know that when you're calling `~Vec3f` for a `Cartesian` object you're not having a leak.